# Columns moved after importing csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python/Pandas. I am wondering if there's a code that can help me fix how the columns move to the right inside the .csv we pull out of our systems - one column is filled with user input (containing messy characters ",) so usually after loading the user input column spreads out on several columns instead of one, wrongly moving out to the right the other columns as well.

I fix this manually in excel, manually filtering, deleting, moving the columns to their correct place - it takes 20 mins / day. 
[image]

I would like to ask advice if there is code which I could try to clean and arrange correctly the columns or if it is easier the manual fix in excel as I do it now.   Thank you!

Comment: Do you know why it spreads out like that? Is it because of the messy characters? What is the text example of such a CSV so we can identify the problem?

Answer (score 2):

pandas is altering the columns because it sees 'separators' in the import file.

In Excel, for each newline, count how many times a comma appears. Using your example above there should be 3 per line.

My quick and dirty solution would be replace the last three commas in your file with a character that is almost impossible for a user to type, I typically go for a pipe '|' character.

Try importing that into pandas, specifying a new delimier/separator example below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep="|")
df.head()
```

Comment: the .csv file already comes separated like that, the user input "Comment" column spread out on 2 or more columns (depending on how many " and ,  the user used and how they used them).  So I'm searching for clean up ways smarter than manually in excel. (Instruct user not to use " or ,  an option? )

Comment: the csv comes separated like this "this is a comment with messy, text"|"colour"|"size1"|"weight" ? Have you tried opening the csv file in notepad

Answer (score 0):

You cannot play with the layout with CSV that is a pure data transport format. Hopefully, there are 3rd party libs that can play with .xlsx files [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [here](http://www.python-excel.org/).